# Elasticsearch: TF-IDF distorting search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.4. I am trying to index a csv file that has 8 fields: `main_name,main_id,sub_name,sub_id,entity_name,entity_id,item_name,item_id`

I am using shingle filter with standard tokenizer and I seem to be getting good matches. Here is the config file:

```
index='my-index',
        body={
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": {
                        "type":     "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 2,
                        "max_gram": 10
                    },
                    "custom_shingle": {
                        "type": "shingle",
                        "min_shingle_size": 2,
                        "max_shingle_size": 3,
                        "output_unigrams": True

                    },
                    "my_char_filter": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": " ",
                        "replacement": ""
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type":      "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            # "autocomplete_filter",
                            "custom_shingle",
                            "my_char_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
        "my_type": {



            "properties": {
                "main_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
            # "index_options": "docs",
            #         "norms": {"enabled": False}

                },
            "main_id": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}

            },
            "sub_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}

            }
            ,
            "sub_id": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}

            }

            ,
            "entity_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}

            }
            ,
            "entity_id": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "keyword",
            "search_analyzer": "keyword"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}

            }
            ,
            "item_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}

            }
    ,
            "item_id": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "keyword",
            "search_analyzer": "keyword"
                # "index_options": "docs",
                # "norms": {"enabled": False}
                }
            }
        }
    }
       }
```

During query execution time, I do a simple multi-match query of type 'best_fields' and highlight matching terms:

```
index="my-index",
            size=100,
            body=
            {

                "query":
                    {
                        "multi_match":
                            {
                                "fields": ["main_name", "main_id", "sub_name", "sub_id",
                                           "entity_name", "entity_id", "item_name", "item_id"],
                                "query": my_original_query,
                                "type": "best_fields",
                                "fuzziness": "1",
                                "tie_breaker": 0.3
                            }
                    },

                "highlight":
                    {

                        "type":"unified",
                        "order": "score",
                        "fields":
                            {
                                "main_name": {},
                                "main_id": {},
                                "sub_name": {},
                                "sub_id": {},
                                "entity_name": {},
                                "entity_id": {},
                                "item_name": {},
                                "item_id": {}

                            }

                    },

            }
```

I get good matches. However, when I query 'Anchor Systems', the top result seems to be 'Detection System' despite 'Anchor Systems' being present in the csv file.(It's an exact match!). I realized that of the 2000 rows in my csv, 1500 contain 'Anchor Systems'. Is this affecting the TF-IDF score? How can I resolve this issue?